# MongoDB and DateTimeOffset type

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to find all documents that are created within a specified time.
I am using c# and the mongodb c# driver.

My entity is as follows:

```
public class Entity
{
    public Gid Id { get; private set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreationTimestamp { get; private set; }
    public Entity()
    {
    }
}
```

So I thought I could do this:

```
DateTime compareTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15);
var result = _collection.Find(Query.GT("CreationTimestamp", compareTime)).Count();
```

Result is a count of zero even though there is data in the collection.
If I change from DateTimeOffset to DateTime I will get back a result.

Is the issue that DateTimeOffset type is not supported?
If so is there a way around this as I need my entities to use DateTimeOffset?

Comment: Updated DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-15); to DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15);

Answer (score 14, accepted):

DateTimeOffset is not serialized as a Date at all, but (by default), as an array of [ticks, timezone offset]. As such, you cannot query it the same way you would a normal date.  Instead, we'll query based on the ticks.  You'll need to make sure your timezone offsets are the same, otherwise this won't work.

```
DateTimeOffsett compareTime = DateTimeOffsett.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15);
var result = _collection.Find(Query.GT("CreationTimestamp.0", compareTime.Ticks)).Count();
```

Basically, we are going to compare the first element of the stored array with the tick count. Sorry again for the time it took to arrive at this answer.

Comment: Craig,When I use FindAll() my CreationTimestamp retrieved from my document is {07/05/2012 16:39:20 +01:00}. When I do a Query.GT("CreationTimestamp", compareTime).ToJson(); my value is "{ \"CreationTimestamp\" : { \"$gt\" : ISODate(\"2012-05-07T15:24:29.037Z\") } }" So I would expect this to return the document

Comment: Yes I have to use DateTimeOffset