# MongoDB C# DateTimeOffset serialization

Tags: c#, mongodb, serialization

I'm storing a `DateTimeOffset` in a Mongo DB using the standard serialization providers.

In the database it looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : LUUID("1197f7cf-cb83-4047-85f8-6e9f8c8ad24f"),
    "CreatedDateTimeUtc" : [ 
        6.3612613922066e+017.0, 
        0
    ]
}
```

But when I try and deserialize in C# the following exception is thrown:

> System.FormatException: An error occurred while deserializing the CreatedDateTimeUtc property of class Turnout.Common.Model.Turnout: ReadInt64 can only be called when CurrentBsonType is Int64, not when CurrentBsonType is Double.

Any ideas on how to get it to play nicely?

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using to perform this deserialization please? Can you also provide your C# model if it is strongly typed, as you may not have the necessary attributes on your properties.

Answer (score 2):

If you still experience this issue, write your own serializer. Have a look at the DateTimeOffsetSerializer MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers for implementation details. I actually use that instead of the default since it includes a readable DateTime.
Register it this way:

```
new BsonStaticsWrapper().RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTimeOffset), new DateTimeOffsetSerializer(BsonType.Document));
```

I know this isn't the exact answer to your question but it might help you get it. And it might help others in finding a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

In the modern ages MongoDB made this a lot easier

```cs
BsonSerializer.RegisterSerializer(typeof(DateTimeOffset), new DateTimeOffsetSerializer(BsonType.DateTime));
```

Afterwards your db entities will have DateTimeOffset serialized like this:

```
CreatedAt: 2012-01-26T12:15:55.000+00:00
```